# Why does numbers.Real not have __gt__ as an abstract (or default) method?

Tags: python, abc

Looking at the source code for [numbers.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/numbers.py#L147) there is no `@abstractmethod` or implementation of `__gt__` or `__ge__`.  Why is this? Is this a bug?

The documentation explicitly says:

> To Complex, Real adds the operations that work on real numbers. In short, those are: a conversion to float, trunc(), divmod, %, <, <=, >, and >=. Real also provides defaults for the derived operations.

As far as I can tell this is not true for `>` and `>=`.

A default implementation should be simple enough, given that the ABC `Real` requires an implementation of `__lt__` and `__le__`. e.g.

```py
def __gt__(self, other):
    return operator.lt(other, self)
```

Again, why is this not the default in `numbers.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default is buggy, and a default would be a bad idea. `a > b` already tries `b.__lt__(a)` if `a.__gt__` doesn't exist or returns `NotImplemented`. Your default leads to infinite recursion with `<` and `__gt__` repeatedly falling back to each other if `other` doesn't know how to compare itself to `self`.

Because the comparison operators fall back to the reversed comparison methods, implementing `__lt__` and `__le__` is enough to make `>` and `>=` work, at least between objects of the same type. It won't be enough to handle `1.0 < MyFloat(1.0)`, though.

Comment: Where do you see that `a > b` tries `b.__lt__(a)` if `a.__gt__` doesn't exist or returns `NotImplemented`?

Comment: @bkanuka: [Data model docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__), for one. See the last paragraph under the comparison operators.

Comment: You can also see it happening in a [simple experiment](https://ideone.com/gALtwk).

Comment: `1.0 < MyFloat(1.0)` not working is exactly what got me to look into this. I understand now. No need to make a user implement a `__gt__` function because with ` __lt__` and `__le__`, a total ordering is defined and therefore the technical/mathematical requirements for a Real-like object are satisfied.